# How should trained ML models be incorporated into a package that USES those trained models

Tags: r, package

I have been working on a ML project for which that work (done inside an R-project) resulted in some ML models (built with caret)  ALONG WITH code that uses those models for additional analysis.

As the next phase, I am "deploying" these models by creating an R-package that my collaborators can use for analysis of new data, where that analysis includes USING the trained ML models.  This package includes functions that generate reports, where, embedded in that report is the application of the trained ML models  against the new data sets.

I am trying to identify the "right" way to include those trained models in the package.  (Note, currently each model is saved in its own .rds file).

I want to be able to use those models inside of package functions.

I also want to consider the possibility of "updating" the models to a new version at a later date.

So ... should I:

1. Include the .rda files in inst/exdata
2. Include as part of sysdata.rda
3. Put them in an external data package (which seems reasonable, except almost all examples in tutorials expect a data package to
   include data.frame-ish objects.)

With regard to that third option ... I note that these models likely imply that there are some additional "NAMESPACE" issues at play, as the models will require a whole bunch of caret related stuff to be useable.   Is that NAMESPACE modification required to be in the "data" package or the package that I am building that will "use" the models?

Answer (score 0):

My first intention is to go for 1.  There is no need to go for other formats as PMML as you only want to run it within R. So I consider Rda as natively best. As long, as your models are not huge, it should be fine to share with collaborators (but maybe not for a CRAN package).  I see, that 3. sounds convenient but why seperate models and functions? Freshly trained models then would come with a new package version, as you anayway would need to go with a data package. I dont see gaining much this way, but I have not much experiance with data packages.